# ODBC trace not stopping

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-server-2008-r2, trace

We have a server that is constantly running an ODBC trace, fortunately it's only a test server but it still keeps filling up its C drive. We have other servers similar to this one without the issue.

Tracing is off and it still writes to the log file after a reboot, I've deleted reg entries that point to the file which haven't returned but still logging. I have also deleted and recreated the ODBC connections to no avail however with the ODBC deleted it didn't seem to log.

Is there anything I've missed? I couldn't find anything on SE similar to this issue, mostly not logging or creating the file at all.

Thanks.

[Added a pic of the ODBC setting and the log file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P3hf.png)

Comment: Have you used RegEdit to search the full registry for anything pointing to sql.log?  Any chance this is a [32-bit vs 64-bit issue](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) -- that tracing is off in one, but not in the other?

Comment: Yes, I found two entries to sql.log which I removed as they were not present on the other servers.

Tracing is off on both 32 and 64.

Comment: I would expect such to show up via RegEdit, but possibly worth checking anyway -- any driver-specific or DSN-specific tracing?

Comment: Nothing that I can see. If I can't work it out soon I think I'll have to trash the server and start again as the log is now touching 1GB.

Comment: I trust you've looked at the file's content, and confirmed that it's really an ODBC trace?  If so, you should be able to identify the client process, among other things, which may help in tracking down the OFF switch.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally found a hidden config file in one of our apps that had an ODBC trace toggle, that is now off.